# Can a sequence $X_n$ of positive random variables converge to infinity almost surely with expectations remaining bounded?

Tags: probability-theory, limits, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Is there some probability space $ (Ω, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ and a sequence $(X_n)$ of positive random variables on $Ω$ for which $X_n → ∞ $ almost surely, but the sequence $\mathbb E[X_n]$ of expectations is bounded (or more generally does not converge to $∞$)?

The monotone convergence theorem tells us no *monotone* sequence of this kind exists, and I think this is also not possible when $Ω$ is finite or countable. Intuitively, the a.s. convergence of the $X_n$ would have to be very non-uniform, but I have not managed to come up with an example.

Comment: Did you try Fatou's lemma?

Comment: Yes, this does the trick! Thanks.

Comment: @fwd Wow, this lemma is so easy to forget. Everyone remembers theorems like monotone convergence, or dominated convergence, but this one is often forgotten. Not a surprise, given that it gives us much less. But sometimes it is very useful.

Comment: It is not going to be possible with positive random variables, but is possible more generally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by user fwd in the comments, no such sequence exists as a consequence of Fatou's lemma, according to which

$$ \mathbb ∞ = \mathbb E[\liminf_{n → ∞} X_n] \leq \liminf_{n → ∞} \mathbb E[X_n]. $$

---

Edit: as also pointed out in the comments, if we drop the requirement $X_n \geq 0$, such a sequence exists, e.g. with $ Ω = (0,1]$ equipped with the Borel-σ-algebra and Lebesgue measure and
$$ X_n = -n^2 I_{(0,1/n)} + n I_{[1/n,1]}.
$$

Comment: Would you mind explaining this in more detail ? I don't understand what follows from Fatou's lemma. Thanks.

Comment: @mark leeds Not at all! The original question was whether it is possible for a sequence of RVs $X_n \geq 0 $ to converge a.s. to $∞$ while the seq. of expectations $\mathbb E[X_n]$ remains bounded. By a.s. convergence, the lim inf of the sequence equals $∞$ a.s., and since $X_n \geq 0$, Fatou's lemma tells us that $\liminf_{n → ∞} \mathbb E[X_n] = ∞$. But then $\mathbb E[X_n] → ∞$ as $n → ∞$.

Comment: Thanks jro. I'll print out the question and your answer and make sure I understand. It's very much appreciated.

Comment: That was so helpful. Your explanation helped it hit me that the liminf and the limit were the same !!!!!!